# What sort of resharper specific files does resharper generate in your vs.net project?

Tags: resharper

What sort of resharper specific files does resharper generate in your vs.net project?

(BTW, did you guys get the full version or just the C# version?)

Answer (score 13):

The "_Resharper.[Solution Name]" folder stores the Resharper specific cache. You can go to Resahrper > Options dialog and select "Store caches in: system TEMP folder" so that your solution folder is not cluttered.

I personally prefer to use the TEMP folder so that the cache does not accidentally get added to the version control. Also, in case you want to clean the cache you can use the "Clear Caches" button on the Resharper Options dialog.

Answer (score 6):

Couple of different things:

1. A folder called "_ReSharper.[Solution Name]" which then contains a collection of files and folder beneath that
2. A file called "[Solution Name].[ReSharper Version].resharper.user"

Both are created in the root of solution next to the .sln file. You can delete them if necessary and ReSharper will just recreate them on next load. Keep them out of your source control management system - they serve no purpose under verison control.