# What ReSharper files should I keep and what files should I ignore in Source Control?

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, resharper

So, which files should I keep and which ones can I ignore when commiting in Mercurial (or any other source control service)?

Or am I expected to keep them all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy rule of thumb is to ignore all of the ReSharper files. They are local caches and user-specific settings that don't belong in source control.

Some exeption could be things like key maps and/or code templates (if you want to share.)

Comment: You may choose to have a "per solution" scheme for resharper. In this case, you want to commit the resharper file - but only one of them. The others such as chache, etc, you need to ignore.

Answer (score 7):

Recommendations for ReSharper (and VisualStudio) ignores for Git are [here:](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore)

```
## Ignore Visual Studio temporary files, build results, and
## files generated by popular Visual Studio add-ons.

# User-specific files
*.suo
*.user
*.sln.docstates

# Build results

[Dd]ebug/
[Rr]elease/
x64/
build/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/

# MSTest test Results
[Tt]est[Rr]esult*/
[Bb]uild[Ll]og.*

*_i.c
*_p.c
*.ilk
*.meta
*.obj
*.pch
*.pdb
*.pgc
*.pgd
*.rsp
*.sbr
*.tlb
*.tli
*.tlh
*.tmp
*.tmp_proj
*.log
*.vspscc
*.vssscc
.builds
*.pidb
*.log
*.scc

# Visual C++ cache files
ipch/
*.aps
*.ncb
*.opensdf
*.sdf
*.cachefile

# Visual Studio profiler
*.psess
*.vsp
*.vspx

# Guidance Automation Toolkit
*.gpState

# ReSharper is a .NET coding add-in
_ReSharper*/
*.[Rr]e[Ss]harper

# TeamCity is a build add-in
_TeamCity*

# DotCover is a Code Coverage Tool
*.dotCover

# NCrunch
*.ncrunch*
.*crunch*.local.xml

# Installshield output folder
[Ee]xpress/

# DocProject is a documentation generator add-in
DocProject/buildhelp/
DocProject/Help/*.HxT
DocProject/Help/*.HxC
DocProject/Help/*.hhc
DocProject/Help/*.hhk
DocProject/Help/*.hhp
DocProject/Help/Html2
DocProject/Help/html

# Click-Once directory
publish/

# Publish Web Output
*.Publish.xml
*.pubxml

# NuGet Packages Directory
## TODO: If you have NuGet Package Restore enabled, uncomment the next line
#packages/

# Windows Azure Build Output
csx
*.build.csdef

# Windows Store app package directory
AppPackages/

# Others
sql/
*.Cache
ClientBin/
[Ss]tyle[Cc]op.*
~$*
*~
*.dbmdl
*.[Pp]ublish.xml
*.pfx
*.publishsettings

# RIA/Silverlight projects
Generated_Code/

# Backup & report files from converting an old project file to a newer
# Visual Studio version. Backup files are not needed, because we have git ;-)
_UpgradeReport_Files/
Backup*/
UpgradeLog*.XML
UpgradeLog*.htm

# SQL Server files
App_Data/*.mdf
App_Data/*.ldf

# =========================
# Windows detritus
# =========================

# Windows image file caches
Thumbs.db
ehthumbs.db

# Folder config file
Desktop.ini

# Recycle Bin used on file shares
$RECYCLE.BIN/

# Mac crap
.DS_Store
```

Answer (score 2):

The resharper folder will start with and underscore. You can ignore them.

Oh there is an SO discussion on this already and should provide you with good deal of information on what to ignore.

- [How do I keep Resharper Files out of SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69448/how-do-i-keep-resharper-files-out-of-svn)

I keep getting more

- [What sort of resharper specific files does resharper generate in your vs.net project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982118/what-sort-of-resharper-specific-files-does-resharper-generate-in-your-vs-net-proj)